# Run program from RAM on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ram

Is there a way to run a program from the command-line in Windows while forcing Windows to retain the process in RAM only without swaping it to disk?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Guffa - I have a critical process where I must optimize its response time. Having a few extra milliseonds added due to disk access would be very bad.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem, it is the scheduler that's going to ruin your day.  You can't boost your thread priority high enough to avoid losing the processor.  Losing 45 msec is to be expected.  You will need to write a device driver, it will give you both the priority boost you need and the option to lock both code and data pages.  Can't run that from the command-line though ;)

Comment: You could use a RAM disk.  There are some third-party products, I believe, some of which may be inexpensive or free.  I'm inclined to agree with Hans, though, that this isn't likely to help much.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no way you can safely and reliably prevent a normal application from seeing page faults (either with load from disk, or just pages rearranged in the pool). It is not normally a problem either.

Page faults (without disk access) happen all the time, and they take a few dozen nanoseconds. Windows routinely moves pages in and out of a very small working set. This does not mean that the pages outside your working set are "gone", but they are *possible candidates* for being swapped/discarded, if someone asks for more memory. Most of the time, when a page outside your working set is accessed again, it is still there and is just silenly moved back into the working set, pushing another one (presumably the least important one) out.
Reloading pages (data or program code) from disk, which is much slower, does not usually happen very often, as long as the program is actually running and as long as the machine is not desperately low on RAM. And if it happens, frankly, there's not much one could have done differently, because that means there simply was less RAM than was neeeded.

You can use `VirtualLock` to lock pages of your address space (any pages, including those occupied by code), but this is still no hard guarantee (even though the documentation would make you believe that) and it only works as far as the working set goes, which by default is *very* little (a little more than 1 MiB).
The best guarantee that locking will give you, however, is that the pages you lock are in RAM while your process is running. Which means, in theory, they might *still* be swapped out at the next context switch anyway when your process is not running.

However, if you give your application a sufficiently large maximum working set size ([`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) then page faults (in code, or in general) are extremely unlikely to happen.
Note that the vast majority of programs is resident in memory most of the time even after they have finished running (buffer cache).